# Android Register Screen using Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I tried to implement an Register Screen with Volley for android (School project). So far I finished the code but the register does not work. I tried to debug it and noticed the server gives me error 500 an internal server error. On my user interface it gives me a com.android.volley.server.

I double checked my url and code but everything seems to be fine. The url is fine because with the same url I can make requests via Postman. And code I could not find any mistakes as I am new to android and volley.. Maybe someone could give me a pointer. My school gave me a google.json file but I do not know if I am allowed to post it here.

This is my method where I make the request:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    public void registerData() {
        userName = Username.getText().toString();

        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String MsgType = jsonobj.getString("MsgType");
                        if(MsgType.equals(1)){
                            Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "Geklappt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "Fail: " + error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Username", userName);
                params.put("Password", password);
                return params;

            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);

    }
```

This is serverResposne which I can get (json)

```
    {
        "MsgType": 1,
        "Info": "Benutzer erfolgreich angelegt",
        "Data": null
    }

Parameters which the server accepts (tested postman)
        {"Username":"Fds", 
        "Password":"Gdg"}
```

Here is the error as asked

```
  E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
D/HwAutofillHelper: recordCurrentInfo:0
    inputType = 131073
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7a31358250 disconnect failed
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/Volley: [38804] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://palaver.se.paluno.uni-due.de/api/user/register
D/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_send_event: wp = 257, ret = 0
D/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_send_event: wp = 258, ret = 0
D/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_send_event: wp = 260, ret = 0
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Can you add exact error which you got in your question as well ?

Comment: Step 1: don't use Volley. Use Retrofit instead.

Comment: I added the error code to my question. Further more I am getting status 500 when I look at the debugger variables

Comment: why? @Zun I mean is there no way to do this with volley

Comment: In Retrofit you can do this with only 2 lines of code. Your code is 44 lines

Comment: That is maybe true but I am new to this whole concept and now started with Volley. Is there no way you can help me with volley

Comment: @haso I can help you if you use Retrofit